# MySQL unique index accept non unique insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I created an unique index (`id_contact_2`) over columns `id_contact`, `id_rubrique` and `poste` as you can see in the screenshot below:

```
CREATE TABLE poste (

    id_poste    int          NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_contact  int          NOT NULL,
    id_rubrique int          NOT NULL,
    poste       varchar(255)     NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY ( id_poste ),

    CONSTRAINT UNIQUE ( id_contact, id_rubrique, poste )
);

CREATE INDEX id_contact ON poste ( id_contact );
```

[image]

Despite this unique index I can add the same value for more than one row.
Have you an idee of hos this can be possible?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What problem does this `UNIQUE` index solve, though? Supposing someone wants to send a short message like just "Hello" twice to the same recipient (but say, a year apart)?

Comment: Also, why isn't your `poste` column `NOT NULL`? Why do you allow `NULL` there?

Comment: In french 'poste' mean 'position', like your position in a company, it can be null because we can know where a person work (id_rubrique), but not his position

Comment: Those four rows are not duplicate of each other, since nulls cannot be compared to anything (nulls or scalar values). Don't treat nulls as values.

Comment: @digitalway Ah, my apologies - I thought it was a table for text messages ("posts").

Comment: We need to check the collation; please provide `SHOW CFREATE TABLE`.